# unable to get value using @Value("${connection.local}")from properties file

Tags: java, spring

i have properties like this

connection.local=0.0.0.0
i write it on application.properties and at application-local.properties it is correct or not ?

but when i want to get this value with annotation

i use plain java for build apps. and use spring context for get value and annotations

```
 @Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Slf4j
@Configuration

public class SocketEngine extends Thread {
    
    /**
     * This is to make sure that the server is running and trying even when
     * idxdatafeed disconnects
     */
    @Value("${connection.local}")
    private String connectionLocalhost;
  
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            Socket server = null;
            String firstData="xvabv";
            try {
                log.info("Connecting to server " + connectionLocalhost+"!");
                server = new Socket(connectionLocalhost, 9010);
                server.setSoTimeout(10000);
                PrintWriter writer= new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream());
```

i got value of connectionLocal is null why like that ?

Comment: where did you put your `connection.local` property?

Comment: i write it on application.properties and at application-local.properties it is correct or not ? @haoyuwang

Comment: Where did you use `connectionLocalhost`?

Comment: Make sure your appliaction.properties is on the root path of your application. And you get the `SocketEngine` instance with `BeanFactory.getBean` method.

Comment: Switch to constructor injection instead of field injection, and you will probably instantly find your problem. [My suspicion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null/) Note that you (1) shouldn't extend `Thread` period, (2) shouldn't directly use threads in most cases (use an executor instead), and (3) _appear_ to be reinventing client code that Spring probably already provides for you.

Comment: yes my application.properties are in src/main/resources so it is on root

Answer (score 0):

You may solve your problem by injecting the value in the constructor:

```
 public SocketEngine(@Value("${connection.local}") String connectionLocalhost) {
    this.connectionLocalhost = connectionLocalhost;

    run();
 }
```

This should resolve the problem. But really I don't why spring here acts like that (tested). Also you don't need the annotation @Compnent because @Configuration includes it.

The official approach is to define the following method in your configuration class:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

But it didn't work, and that's why I'm confused!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the  problem , add like below code.

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```